# Database select same record multiple times using different columns

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ms-access

I have a table of orders with multiple date columns (Department finished dates). I'd like to query the table and return a unique line for each match of a specified date and give a reference to why that line was selected.

So from this table:

```
OrderID   OrderName   Date1      Date2      Date3
456       feh         5/1/2011   6/1/2011   3/1/2011
487       meh         12/1/2010  2/1/2011   8/1/2011
```

If queried for any date greater than 4/1/2011 I would like to return:

```
456       feh         5/1/2011     Date1
456       feh         6/1/2011     Date2
487       meh         8/1/2011     Date3
```

The data is in MS Access and I'm not sure if this is possible at the query level or would require subreports to produce.

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Posted comment in wrong area. Posting up here too: Both union statements work, however, I'd like the last column to be not the dates in the field, but rather, the column name or reason for the match. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get your last column:

```
Select OrderID, OrderName, Date1 as SelDate, 'Date1' as Reason
  from table where date1>'4/21/2011'
UNION ALL  
Select OrderID, OrderName, Date2 as SelDate, 'Date2' as Reason
  from table where Date2>'4/21/2011'
UNION ALL  
Select OrderID, OrderName, Date3 as SelDate, 'Date3' as Reason
  from table where Date3>'4/21/2011'
```

Also note that I changed the alias of the `SelDate` column--even though it's not critical (in Access) when it's an alias, you really should avoid naming columns with Reserved Words.

Comment: That rocks, thanks! Obviously this is 3 hits through the entire record set, correct?

Comment: Hmmm.... Most likely yes, though it's all handled by the query engine (the "server", even though it's actually local in Access), then combined by the Unions before it's returned. Google "Jet showplan" if you really want to find out the details.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select OrderID, OrderName Date1 as Date, 'Date1' as ComparedDate
from table where date1>'4/21/2011'  
UNION ALL  
Select OrderID, OrderName Date2 as Date, 'Date2' as ComparedDate  
from table where Date2>'4/21/2011'  
UNION ALL  
Select OrderID, OrderName Date3 as Date, 'Date1' as ComparedDate
from table where Date3>'4/21/2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable through a query:

```
Select OrderID, OrderName, Date1 as Date 
from table where date1>'4/21/2011'

UNION ALL

Select OrderID, OrderName, Date2 as Date 
from table where Date2>'4/21/2011'

UNION ALL

Select OrderID, OrderName, Date3 as Date 
from table where Date3>'4/21/2011'
```

Comment: Both this and the one above work, the only tweak being I'd like the last column to not contain the date, but rather, contain the header or reason for the match.

Comment: You would need to add another column for that.